# Hindi language support for Android - text shows up as boxes

Tags: android, fonts, android-emulator, internationalization, hindi

Does android in eclipse emulator support hindi fonts? I see Square boxes like
☐ instead of characters अ आ इ ई उ ऊ on Emulator and on Unicode or UTF8 compliant
Hindi websites. Any settings for solving the issue?

Comment: Why django with this question?

Comment: no emulator cant be supported.

Comment: how u fix this problem?

Answer (score 11):

This might help you

use custom TrueType fonts by copying the .ttf file into your projects's 'assets' folder.

Then in your application you can use the font like this;

```
final Typeface customF = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "custom.ttf");
final TextView textV = (TextView) findViewById(...);
textV.setTypeface(customF);
```

Comment: it is also giving same output the boxes.

Answer (score 2):

My hunt for Hindi font in my Android phone LG-P500),

I found some useful tips which I would like share with you all hindi lover. I tried it in opera mini and it is showing Hindi. I also trying hind keypad but still unable write hindi if anybody have any information please share it ..

Hindi reading method in opera mini
1 - First install latest version of "Opera Mini" on Android powered tablet or phone which is available free on Android Market. Otherwise go to official site of opera. (Read about Opera Mini & download)
2 - After that go to address bar & type opera:config and nothing should have www or http://.
3. Then come to the menu & at its end see "use bitmap fonts for complex scripts". No sentence will be written in front of. You change it to Yes.
4. Save it.
Now Open any Hindi site and see hindi font on your mobile / tablet instead of square font.

Your can try the following also…
Install Hindi font (including all Indian language) as system font - go this link:- http://android-bucket.blogspot.com/2011/07/hindi-font-installation-for-advance.html (Only for Advance users)