# Displaying non-English (specifically Hindi) characters on Android device

Tags: android, hindi

I have some Hindi text which is not getting displayed on the virtual device. The text is properly displayed in eclipse, and the files are utf-8 encoded.

E.g. I have this resource file:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>

            <string name="hello">Hello World, Jain_aartisActivity!</string>
            <string name="app_name">जैन आरती संग्रेह</string>
     </resources>
```

But the AVD is unable to display the app_name. It just displays a small rectangle for each hindi character.

Comment: related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759242/hindi-language-support-for-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this ::**

here i have set hindi font in my textview. you can copy file in assets folder and apply following code :

```
Typeface face;
face = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/hindi.TTF");
tran_banner = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tran_banner);
            tran_banner.setTypeface(face, Typeface.BOLD);
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it doesn't seem to work. I downloaded two files from the web hindi.ttf and droidsansfallback.ttf. Do you have a link to your hindi.ttf?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that the default fonts on Android devices contain hindi characters. You'll need to package up a hindi font with your app and use that.