# Android multilingual app development: how to fetch Hindi characters or string from edittext?

Tags: android, hindi

I am developing an Android app which needs to support two languages **Hindi/English**. I am able to convert the whole app UI in Hindi language but the problem is that I don't know how to fetch Hindi characters or string from edittext.

As I am fetching data in general way:

```
String userName=_userEdt.getText().toString();
```

but userName string does not contains any data in Hindi mode.How to I get the word like **हिन्दी** from edittext.

Comment: what is being set to userName when you execute this line?

Comment: it showing unformated data like small boxes.

Comment: i see, you need to download hindi fonts and then associate it with the textview, for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602939/displaying-non-english-specifically-hindi-characters-on-android-device

Answer (score 0):

Download the hindi font “mangal.ttf” supported file and copy it in your font folder, which is created in assets folder. Try this way for implementing multilingual support in app development.