# Android adding additional languages after app is installed

Tags: android, localization, android-resources

I have placed the resources to support different languages in appropriate packages as suggested in Android Localization documentation. Is there a way to add additional languages, i.e, resources after the app is installed without having to download and re-install the app. I mean updating the app - adding new resources and even updating some existing ones.

For example if my app initially supported English and French. Now suppose I want to add new language say Hindi and update few of the resources in English. So what is the approach..?

Comment: you have to place the appropriate language resources inside the resources folder.

Comment: Add a values-hi folder in the res path and a strings.xml file with the Hindi resources in it. look at the [reference page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html). You might also want to use a Hindi-specific font, as stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8603015/2649012)

Comment: How can I add appropriate packages(values-hi) and files(strings.xml) within them after app is installed?

Comment: No... you have to reinstall the app. Share an update to your users. ChangeLog: "Added Hindi language"

Comment: In my question I have clearly mentioned without having to re-install..You are suggesting me the same thing. I have already added languages as given in the documentation.

Comment: @Vyger So you say it is not possible to add languages or resources once the app is installed. Only way is to re-install the updated app(.apk) with new language support & updated resources.

Comment: Yes. OR your app is always connected to an online db that can serve your strings in different languages - but this would be an **overkill**, and really wouldn't be worth the effort!

Comment: Well... I strongly discourage you doing it that way. The upgrade is a much better approach.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, my approach is to create separate folder on the device \data\packageName\languages\
there will be one file called supportedfiles.lang the format of the file will be
English en
Russian ru
...
also in same location you will have the following files
en.lang
ru.lang

the format of each language file ie(en.lang / ru.lang) will be like regular strings.xml
Some text

when you load the application in settings screen you will read the supportedfiles.lang and show to user the supported languages when he choose different language you just need to load the appropriate language file

Maybe it is over kill, but you will have the flexibility to support other languages while the application installed without updating the application just copy the files into /data/package/languages/