# Android localization at runtime example shows empty strings for languages other than English

Tags: android, localization

I'm trying to implement Android Localization (currently for Hindi Language). I found [this](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-localization-at-runtime/) tutorial. However, there is a problem that I'm facing with it.
When I click the Select Language option, I can see only English in the dropdown. The remaining two are invisible. Not quite sure as to what the issue could be.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you showing these strings statically or they are coming from webservice response, because issue is in your arraylist or string array these two strings are empty. Can add your code how you are doing?

Comment: @ReadyAndroid Strings are static. Check my edited question

Comment: your `hi/strings` will be called when u changed the locale to `hi`  default `en` values will be called

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be your used font missing hindi characters. There seems to be various similar questions on stackoverflow that *might* be [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602939/displaying-non-english-specifically-hindi-characters-on-android-device), perhaps [they](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789827/how-can-i-show-hindi-text-in-android-tablet) can help?.

Another option could possibly be the encoding, which you could change similar to (I don't know which is the default encoding though, or whether it already supports Hindi or not):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="string_name">text_string</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

@felix's answer helped me to understand the root cause. 
Basically, the issue was that my emulator did not have Hindi language support. That's why it showed empty strings. 
However, when I ran the same app on my phone, which apparently does have the Hindi language support since I'm in India, it worked like a charm.