# Non-English words in android application

Tags: android

I a content rich application for the Indian market and want to show some text in Hindi (Indian language).

One option is to create image with the text and add the image in the activity. But it becomes too complicated to create and manage images of various sizes.

Is there any way out by which I can display hindi text without messing with the images.

Comment: Have you tried simply displaying the Hindi text in a `TextView`?

Comment: Images are most definitely not the way .. Android supports Unicode, so if anything it's just the rendering of such, [like the choosing the font here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602939/displaying-non-english-specifically-hindi-characters-on-android-device?rq=1) ([and here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759242/hindi-language-support-for-android)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to simply display the text in a `TextView`. If it does not display correctly, it's probably a font problem. You can package a custom font with your app and use it in a `TextView` very simply. Just put a .ttf font file (it needs to support Unicode encoding of your text) in your project's `./assets` folder and include code similar to this in your activity's `onCreate` method:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.view_for_hindi_text);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "MyHindiFont.ttf");
tv.setTypeface(font);
```

Comment: Its not working, it show boxes.

Comment: @RobinHood - It's either a font problem or an encoding problem with the text. "It shows boxes" is, in my experience, always caused by one (or both) of these problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have different strings.xml files for different languages.

As shown in the below documentation 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Pretty sure you get out of the box support for Hindi.