# access string.xml files by other than localization technique

Tags: java, android

I want to add Indian local language functionality to android application, but I am always getting answers for localization of foreign languages.

Making it clear I want to add telugu hindi and tamil (3 Indian local languages) to my application. I created all the string files required for all the three languages. I need help how to use the specific string.xml files as I cannot use localization feature of android since it helps only for international languages. Is there any method which can be used to select a particular string.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Since the Android OS version 2.3.3 (*I think*), Hindi is supported and can be used with the code of **hi_IN**

A `values` folder with the name of **`values-hi`** *should* (should because I have never personally used the **Hindi** language in any app yet!) do the job for you.

To see a list of supported locales, fire up an emulator with the API level you support and check the language in the list in the *Custom Locale* app. If the language is listed here, that particular API supports that language.

Example:

[image]

I started with this tutorial and found it quite helpful: http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/android-application-localization-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

First of all. Many Indian languages are not support yet in android. They have started few with ICS/ JB but still all are not support or rendered properly. It is typical complex script. Refer this issue. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4153 That is resolved for Hindi but not for all languages.

Here is best practices to support multiple languages guideline. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html. What specific need you have?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I want to use language not supported by android OS. I want to add strings of that language to string.xml file and refer to them when required. I am trying to make multi language functionality. Based on the language selected language (i.e non supported language or android), the application should use that language.

Comment: Please see this.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759242/hindi-language-support-for-android-text-shows-up-as-boxes